# PHP: Don't load images until div is expanded?

Tags: php, html, expand

On my site, I have an updates section, which groups updates (galleries) into their own div. Each div is loaded hidden. They choose a section, and it expands to show the new galleries.

That all works fine. However, it loads all the images on the page load, which causes the hour glass to linger longer than I like. Is there any way to make an image load after a div is made visible?

Edit:

Went with:

```
    $(function() {
      $('.collapse img').attr('src', function(index, src) {
         return this.getAttribute('data-src');
      });
    });
```

collapse is the div name that has the images in it. How can this be changed to only change the images in that current div? All the collapsed divs have the same name. However, when expanded, I want it to load only the images in that one div. Right now it loads all the images in all the collapsed div once I expand one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your divs should not contain the images at startup. You can load the images via JavaScript if a user expands your div.

Example:

```
function expandDiv(idOfDivElement) {
    divObj = document.getElementById(idOfDivElement);
    var imageObj = document.createElement('img');
    imageObj.setAttribute('src', 'path/example_image.jpg');
    divObj.appendChild(imageObj);
    // your expand div code here
}
```

You could advance this function and add a second parameter for the image url. Or a array / comma seperated string if you want to load multiple images.

Answer (score 0):

The process of loading images is up to the browser. You should load that content with javascript, like ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the images( within expandable div ) from ajax...
Just make the div visible, and then call ajax to get the images. Then use `.innerHtml()` or if you use jQuery, use `.html()` to put the images in the expanded div.

In this case you have to build the html in ajax page. It will just add the html to the eexpanded div.

This way loads the page much faster.

Please give feedback.

Comment: Why the heck should he use ajax ... as long as the image is not renderd dynamically by a script or something like that there is absolutly NO need for using ajax. He can just add image elements with javascript if he knows the image path.

Comment: He can do as u said, if the image paths are static and he knows them. In that case your answer is absolute perfect, without any competition. But, what if the images are coming from database? I just tried to make them dynamic, like fetching from database, or from folder...